# Send get request to local api from react native mobile project

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, react-native

I am developing a mobile app using react native, SQL Server and NodeJS. 
I got an API in my localhost. I run my application on an emulator and try to get request from API. But I got this message in catch(error):

> [Error:Network Error].

Can somebody help me please.

Comment: Post the code that you have done yet.

Comment: This is my code try to get some values from API
getAxios(){
        var url="https://localhost:44333/api/values"
        axios.get(url)
        .then(response => this.setState(console.log(response)))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }

Comment: use your IP address instead of localhost

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are unable to access the local development server because port hasn't been forwarded by ADB yet. Try to replace the "localhost" with your machine IPv4 address and check else you can also try map your local server port just like React Native does.

To forward a port using ADB run the following command in your terminal 
adb reverse tcp:8163 tcp:8163 remember this only works if you are using Android 6.0+.

Comment: I already try to adb reverse tcp code but it didnt work or ı couldnt